# Separating parcel polygons that share boundaries in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, symbology, arcgis-10.4, boundaries

I have parcels in one layer which are simple polygons. As one parcel is against it's neighbor the lines of that boundary are shared.  This makes it very difficult to symbolize the parcels in different outline colors.

I found a way to deal with it here: [Displaying adjacent polygon lines beside each other instead of overlapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113148/displaying-adjacent-polygon-lines-beside-each-other-instead-of-overlapping)

Unfortunately, this fix does not hold when I export into KMZ using the Map to KML tool.

Can someone help me figure out a solution for this that can give me a good solution in the end product of a Google Earth KMZ file?

[image]

This is what I am actually dealing with in GE.
[image]

Comment: What about the other solution doesn't work for you?  What happens when you try this with KMZ that you don't like?

Comment: Convert to lines, show common line as blue/green line. Place transparent polygons underneath, so click inside will bring polygons info

Comment: @Midavalo The solution of changing the outline to a negative works GREAT inside of Arcmap, but the output to KML/KMZ Google Earth renders the polygon lines in the same position before the outline offset... basically, there is NO change.

Comment: @JimGarner please [edit] your question to include all this information

Comment: Thank you @FelixIP but that will not work for my needs.  I have colored symbology for each parcel based on WHO is working on it.  So that in GE the users can see outlined colors far away or zoomed in.  There are many so clicking to get the color is not going to help.

Comment: Why not just fill in the polygons by colour of who is working on it? If it is just a matter of visualising who is working where why do you need to see whats underneath the polygon? You can always turn off the layer in GE to see whats underneath or have a second layer with outlines when you turn off the fill layer

Comment: @Clubdebambos thank you.  The aerial lay of the land and objects on it should remain visible.  I have also tried with different levels of opacity.  A thin hatch might work. But it would be better to unshared those boundaries.

Comment: Just a thought; try polygon to line, this should make clockwise linear features for each polygon. Then buffer these lines by say 2m or 5m to the right side only. Use the buffer layer as your boundary.  This will be a thin sliver polygon around your working areas but they wont overlap, use a fill and no outline perhaps. You may need to transfer attributes there.

Comment: @Clubdebambos thank you for the suggestion. I will have to try it next week.  Until then, I wanted to show you a picture of what I am getting in GE so you can consider if this will still work:

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2MFETPitIUiWDRGNGI4TUk0VTQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Also added to edited question as a picture image.

Comment: @JimGarner my last suggestion might be a bit convoluted, here's a better sggestion: use a negative buffer might be just the job to use. Experiment with the (minus) Linear unit distance (-0.25m, -0.5m, -1m etc) this will create a small gap between all polygons and allow you to have thick outlines that don't overlap. I have tested and seems to work well. I have added as an answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative buffer to offset the boundaries of the polygons. This will create a slight gap between each polygon allowing for the outline boundary not to overlap. Experiment with the negative number until you are satisfied. Set the Input, Output and (minus) Linear Unit, the rest of the fields can be left as default.The attribute values will remain in-tact for the output.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think this is going to work!  Thank you.  I have to take it over to Google Earth to be sure, but I will mark it as answer as soon as I do.  Be back soon!

Comment: How do I mark this as an ANSWER?  I clicked the button [POST YOUR ANSWER] but it appears to want ME to provide the answer.    Um.... Found it!

Comment: Although this is an answer for me to use, as the poster realizes this solution is dependent upon the zoom level of Google Earth.  If anyone knows how to do this function EXCEPT with a setting to ALWAYS TOUCH, that would solve the issue.  In essence, property parcels should have an option of each one having their own boundary sides, regardless of zoom.

Comment: CAUTION: After trying to use this solution, it just does not work.  Much thanx to the contributor @Clubdebambos.  I believe we need an option to make non-coincidental lines, but lines that always appear to be touching, nonetheless.

If Google Earth would allow the negative outline option this WOULD BE the solution, but I cannot see any option to do this.

Perhaps there is a way in the Keyhole Markup Language that is allowed.  Any thoughts?